# Contour integral of $f(z)=\frac{z^2}{(z-1)^2(z+2)}$ around the circle of radius $3$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to find the contour integral of $f (z) = z ^ 2 / ((z-1) ^ 2 \cdot (z + 2))$ along the circle of radius $3$ and center $(0,0)$.
I reasoned like this: in the integrand there are two singularities which are $1$ and $-2$ so I applied the integral formula of the Cauchy derivatives and I considered the starting integral as the sum of the following two integrals:

1. Integral along the circumference of radius $\varepsilon$ and center $-2$ of $f (z) / (z + 2)$ where $f (z) = z ^ 2 / (z-1) ^ 2$
2. Integral along the circumference of radius $\varepsilon$ and center $1$ of $g (z) / (z-1) ^ 2$ where $g (z) = z ^ 2 / (z + 2)$.
   The sum of these two integrals for the formula is:
   $(2\pi i\cdot f (- 2)) / 0! + (2\pi i\cdot g'(1)) / 1!$

Is it correct?

Comment: Welcome. Myself and another user have edited your post using MathJax; it is essentially as simple as writing `$` before and after an equation, like this: `$f(z)=z^2/(z-1)^2$` renders nicely as $f(z)=z^2/(z-1)^2$, and `$\pi$` renders nicely as $\pi$, rather than using a unicode character!

Comment: ok thank you very much

Comment: Why do you use radius $3$ at first but then radius $\varepsilon$?

Comment: because I want to consider a generic circumference contained in that of center (0,0) and radius 3 but which contains only a singularity.

Comment: There is no $(0,0)$ in $\Bbb C$. My guess is that you meant $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Your argument is not quite right, since you have split your function into two functions which don't add up to the original one.

You should approach it like this:

$$f(z)=\frac{z^2}{(z+2)(z-1)^2}=\frac{4}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{z+2}+\frac{5}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}$$

And then use *these* functions, which you *can* use the linearity of the integral to split with.

You should get your answer as just $2\pi i$.

Alternatively, you could have used a more powerful tool called the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem).